# Handling "refresh" or "back" in AJAX to keep "parent" html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I'm fairly new to AJAX, I have a simple 3 page project which I am using AJAX to transition between pages.

I have an index.html page which loads all the html / body / scripts etc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax practice</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="" id="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="aboutBtn" href="main.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="aboutBtn" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="aboutBtn" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a class="aboutBtn" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="page wrapper" id="page">
            <div class="circle" id="black"></div>
            <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
            <div class="circle" id="blue"></div>

            <section class="mainSplash main">


                <div class="mainSplash__content" id="content">

                </div>


            </section>
        </div> <!-- page -->
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my 2 pages are:

main.html:

```
<h1 class="mainSplash__header--h1">Main</h1>
```

about.html:

```
<h1 class="mainSplash__header--h1">About</h1>
```

Here is the AJAX which transitions the pages:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


  var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only

  console.log(pathname);

    // $('.mainSplash').css('height',$(window).height() - 60);

    $(".aboutBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pageTitle =  $(this).text();
        var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        changePage(pageUrl, true, pageTitle);
    }); // click

    function changePage(url, bool, pageTitle){
        $('#page').addClass('fadeOut');

        loadContent(url, bool, pageTitle);
    }

    function loadContent(url, bool, pageTitle){
      $.ajax({
        url: './' + url,
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
          $('#page').one('animationend',
            function(e) {
            // load content
            $('#page').removeClass('fadeOut');
            $('#page').addClass('fadeIn');
            $('#content').html(data);
            //$("html").html(data);
            // Change url
            if(url != window.location){
              window.history.pushState({path: url}, pageTitle, url);
            }
          });
                }
        });
    }

  function removeAnimation(){
    $('#page').removeClass('animate');
  }

});
```

So my transitions work fine when I have come from index.html, though when I refresh main.html or about.html, they do not keep the code from index.html (obviously).

> My question is:

How do I handle a refresh or back button from my pages without losing the index.html content? Any help or advice is appreciated - thank you in advance.

PS: If anyone knows of any AJAX html page transition examples I would love to know so I can improve my code, as I'm looking for best practice for AJAX transitions!

Answer (score 0):

multi way available to do this but best way is use hash routing. see this plugin  '[Routei](http://projects.jga.me/routie/) '.set param in hash route then and get it when click on back button and handel ajax whit this param.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the browser page `hash` and on navigation check for the given hash and load the corresponding page.

```
let hash = window.location.hash;
```

When the hash changes, your browser adds a new history for that page.

Answer (score 0):

On the load of the Site you need to add entry in the history with the command history.pushState and to go back to use the buttons of the browser you will need the EventListener onpopstate